# xlwt cannot format number to date

Tags: django

Why the following code can't format `44000` to a date in excel? It shows up in xls file as the original number no matter what I try.

Things I have tried:

- Different format string, none works. I copy them from source file so no mistake here
- Check `style` object with breakpoint, it gets the correct `num_format_str`
- quote or un-quote the number

I am using Mac Preview to open the xls file if that's relevant.

```
    import xlwt

    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
    sheet = book.add_sheet('sheet 1')        
    style = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str="M/D/YY") 
    sheet.write(1, 1, 44000, style=style)

    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.xls'
    book.save(response)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is with no problem. Problem is with Mac Preview.. I open the file in Excel on Windows and `44400` shows as date.